# How make DRF return 200 instead of 302 on successful login?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an API that is powered by the Django REST Framework.

When I make a *successful* login to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth/login/`, the server answers this request with a `302` status code, that redirects me to `/accounts/profile/`. Its worth noting that a *failing* login is answered with a `200` by the server.

**How can we change this behavior?** I want

- a *successful* login to be answered with a `200` or some other *acknowledging* status code
- and a *failing* login to be answered with some appropriate *error* code, instead of an "ok". I think that the "ok", that the `200` status code means, is very misleading here.

Comment: What you need to understand here is that, the response status codes are not relevant to your login action, they are status code of the handling of your request for login. 200 means that request for login was successfully made, and a valid response has been received. It does not matter if login was successful or not. Also 302 means that a redirect to another page was made when requested for login. It can not be changed until you stop redirection on successful login. Please read about [http response status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Comment: Also for unsuccessful login you can manually send a response with status 401, which is for un-authorized requests.

Comment: @SaurabhGoyal Thanks a lot for that clarification. Is there any way to get whether the login was successful from the response?

Comment: @SaurabhGoyal If you write an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, see my comment on question for clarification(I don't want to repeat the content by copy-pasting in answer).

As for the question of detecting login success in response, we have three basic cases-

**1) successful login-** page is redirected to profile, 302 is sent. Just check for response status code 302.

**2) unsuccessful login(invalid credentials)-** Send 401(unauthorized requests) and check for the same.

**3) unsuccessful login(valid credentials but not authorized to access the page due to any number of reasons)-** Send 403(forbidden i.e. user is not allowed to access the page) and check for response status code 403.

Hope it helps, please go through Http response status codes.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to check for status code 302, at least when using JQuery's AJAX module, because the redirect is processed at a lower layer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should change the status code from 302 to 200 in case of successful login.

As per the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for  HTTP 302 status code:

> The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI.
>   Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD
>   continue to use the Request-URI for future requests. This response is
>   only cacheable if indicated by a `Cache-Control` or `Expires` header
>   field.

This is because you wanted to access your profile resource using the Request-URI `/api-auth/login/` but that resource is currently present at a temporary location or URI `/accounts/profile/`. Now since the resource was found but at a temporary location i.e it was moved temporarily, it returned a 302 status code.

Also, using 302 status code is better because of its compatibility with most browsers.